# Using sklearn StandardScaler on only select columns

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array X that has 3 columns and looks like the following:

```
array([[    3791,     2629,        0],
       [ 1198760,   113989,        0],
       [ 4120665,        0,        1],
       ...
```

The first 2 columns are continuous values and the last column is binary (0,1). I would like to apply the StandardScaler class only to the first 2 columns. I am currently doing this the following way:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_subset = scaler.fit_transform(X[:,[0,1]])
X_last_column = X[:, 2]
X_std = np.concatenate((X_subset, X_last_column[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
```

The output of X_std is then:

```
array([[-0.34141308, -0.18316715,  0.        ],
       [-0.22171671, -0.17606473,  0.        ],
       [ 0.07096154, -0.18333483,  1.        ],
       ...,
```

Is there a way to perform this all in one step? I would like to include this as part of a pipeline where it will scale the first 2 columns and leave the last binary column as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since scikit-learn version 0.20 you can use the function [sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using a class to select columns like this:

```
class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_array):
        return data_array[:, self.columns]
```

I then used FeatureUnion in my pipeline as follows to fit StandardScaler only to continuous variables:

```
FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[
        ('continous', Pipeline([  # Scale the first 2 numeric columns
            ('selector', ItemSelector(columns=[0, 1])),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler())
        ])),
        ('categorical', Pipeline([  # Leave the last binary column as is
            ('selector', ItemSelector(columns=[2]))
        ]))
    ]
)
```

This worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of another way to compact you code more, but you can definitely use your transformation in a Pipeline. You have to define a class extending StandardScaler that only performs the transformations on the columns passed as arguments, keeping the others intact. See the code in this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html), you would have to program something similar to ItemSelector.

Comment: Thank you. The ItemSelector class you linked and FeatureUnion are what I would need to put this into a Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by skd's recommendation to extend StandardScaler, I came up with the below. It's not super efficient or robust (e.g., you'd need to update the inverse_transform function), but hopefully it's a helpful starting point:

```
class StandardScalerSelect(StandardScaler):

    def __init__(self, copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True, cols=None):
        self.cols = cols
        super().__init__(copy, with_mean, with_std)

    def transform(self, X):

        not_transformed_ix = np.isin(np.array(X.columns), np.array(self.cols), invert=True)

        # Still transforms all, just for convenience. For larger datasets
        # will want to modify self.mean_ and self.scale_ so the dimensions match,
        # and then just transform the subset
        trans = super().transform(X)

        trans[:,not_transformed_ix] = np.array(X.iloc[:,not_transformed_ix])

        return trans
```